# Change font colour of bringhurst chapterstyle in memoir

Tags: sectioning, color, memoir, chapters

I would like to change the colour of chapter titles in bringhurst chapterstyle. The following should work, but apparantly I have misunderstood something and am not able to get it to work, and would appreciate any pointers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document} 

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{}{\color{red}}

\chapter{test} 

Some text here

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used p. 362 of the manual as a starting point, but had to correct a severe typo (`{##1}` -- corrrect is `{#1}`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document} 

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \memRTLraggedright\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
}

\chapter{test}

Some text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason you need to change `##1` into `#1` is because the code isn't anymore inside a macro.